# Intersectional Observer Navigation with Squarespace

Tags: javascript, java, css, squarespace

Page Link: https://www.ryanewanchuk.com/case-studies/fellowkidsblacklight

Password: `SquarespaceDemoHelp!`

**EDITED/UPDATED POST BELOW!**

Hi,

So I have been working on making my navigation change colour based on what the current visible page content background colour is. Surprisingly, I did manage to get it working for the most part, but I am having a few issues I am hoping to get help with.

Problem/Goals

1. When the navigation reaches the first trigger, it changes as it should. However, when it reaches another area below that matches the same criteria, it does nothing. I would like to find a way to make the intersectional observer trigger on multiple sections, and ideally I want to be able to reorder sections and not have any issues.
2. When the navigation changes to black, and the menu is activated via the burger and then closed, the navigation returns to the original colour. I would like to keep the navigation colour the same after the menu is closed.
3. When the menu is opened, it only takes one colour theme. I would like the observer to change the menu overlay as well as the nav colour. This isn't as important as the other two.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    const sectionOne = document.querySelector(".black-section");
    
    const sectionOneOptions = {
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: .6
    };
      
    
      
    let prevYPosition = 0
    let direction = 'up'
    
    const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
      entries,
      sectionOneObserver
    ) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
          header.classList.add("white")
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("white")
        }
      });
    },
    sectionOneOptions);
    
    sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne);
```

**EDIT!**

I have managed to get code working so that it basically is doing what I want. When a section with the class "page-section.black" is within the ratio I've set, it changes the nav - and in reverse as well.

However, it seems to work very well in Safari, but not as well in Chrome. In Chrome, it appears that when I have added any content to a section that it no longer see's it as ".page-section.black" or it is just very random. Again, it works fine in Safari. Perhaps it is a glitch with Squarespace and Chrome.

Could anyone take a look at the new code posted below and let me know if there is anything that may cause this issue? This is my first dive into Java, and I really need to get my site working so I can apply for jobs. Thanks so much!

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.page-section.black');
const config = {
  rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px -50px',
  threshold: [.2, .5]
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
        //intersection ratio bigger than 90%
        //-> set header according to target
            header.classList.remove("white")
            header.classList.add("black")     
      } else {
        
            header.classList.remove("black")
            header.classList.add("white")   
        
      } 
    }
  });
}, config);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

Comment: You are currently only observing the first section which has class black-section. Are you wanting to observe all sections or all sections with that class or ....

Comment: Hi, yeah I want it to trigger every time it hits a section with that class because there will be multiple scattered throughout a page.

Comment: If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. This is my first dive into Java and there is absolutely no documentation on applying it within Squarespace.